# How to export Crystal report to PDF and email in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, crystal-reports

I am trying to convert a crystal report to pdf as I need to mail it. So I looked tried few steps but to no avail.
I tried:

```
  RPTBanQoute printbanqoute = new RPTBanQoute();
            printbanqoute.SetDataSource(ds);               

            printbanqoute.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, @"E:\ASD.pdf");
```

In this nothing happens.

Then I tried :

```
            try
            {
                // Export the Report to Response stream in PDF format and file name Customers
                //printbanqoute.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Customers");
                printbanqoute.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, Response, true, "Quotation");
                // There are other format options available such as Word, Excel, CVS, and HTML in the ExportFormatType Enum given by crystal reports
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                ex = null;
            }
```

Getting an error on `Response` as `The name 'Response' does not exist in the current context`

I tried using Server.Mappath but intellisense doesnt show Mappath. I used System.Web

Heres how I am populating data onto Crystal reprt :

```
  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT tb.BookingID, BookingDate, Event, EventDate, EventTime, Pax, Service, ServiceTime, f.FoodMenu, f.ExtraItem FROM tblBookingDetails tb, tblMenu f WHERE tb.BookingID = @bookid AND tb.BookingID = f.BookingID", con.con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookid", BLDashboard.bookingID);
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet1 ds = new DataSet1();
            adapter.Fill(ds, "BookingDetails");
            if (ds.Tables["BookingDetails"].Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Data Found", this.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            RPTBanQoute printbanqoute = new RPTBanQoute();
            printbanqoute.SetDataSource(ds);
```

I am also passing parameter values to this Crystal report.

So please advice how to achieve converting to PDF and email

Also I googled further and tried these codes :

```
 cryRpt = new ReportDocument();  
          cryRpt.Load("E:\\Office\\Clients\\Bombay Restaurant\\Banquet New - MySql\\Banquet New\\RPTBanQoute.rpt");  
          crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;  
          crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();  
          try  
          {  
              ExportOptions CrExportOptions;  
              DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();  
              PdfRtfWordFormatOptions CrFormatTypeOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();  
              CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = "c:\\csharp.net-informations.pdf";  
              CrExportOptions = cryRpt.ExportOptions;  
              {  
                  CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;  
                  CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;  
                  CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;  
                  CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = CrFormatTypeOptions;  
              }  
              cryRpt.Export();  
          }  
          catch (Exception ex)  
          {  
              MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());  
          }
```

But this gave me exception :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve my issue. I was writing all codes in `crystalviewer1_Load` event ie; exporting and email as well as populating data to crystal report. So I had to create a Button Email to export and email.
Heres my code to export and email, Button1 is the email button on crystalviewer:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            billprint.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "E:\\" + filename);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

        }
        try
        {
            MailMessage mm = new MailMessage();
            string toemail = BLDashboard.email;
            string custnm = BLDashboard.custname;

            mm.From = new MailAddress("operations@kaem.in", "Kashif Ahhmed");
            mm.To.Add(new MailAddress(toemail, custnm));
            mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
            string name = BLDashboard.custname;
            mm.Subject = "Bill from Indian Restaurant";
            //mm.Body = "Testing Crsytel Report Attachment send via Email";

            String Body = "<div>Hello " + name + ",<br> Thank you for considersing us for your next Party/Event, here is the Bill for the Party/Event.<br> If any queries you can reach us at 6096464445. <br> Thank You</div>";
            mm.Body = Body;
            //mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(rpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat), fileName));  
            mm.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("E:\\" + filename));



            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.kaem.in");
            sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emailadd", "*********");
            sc.Send(mm);
            // MailMessage msg = mm.CreateMailMessage("mr.markwhite1@gmail.com", replacements, Body, new System.Web.UI.Control());  
            MessageBox.Show("Email successfully sent to " + toemail);
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Unable to send email to mr.markwhite1@gmail.com due to following error:\n\n" + e1.Message, "Email send error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            //{
            //    this.SendEmail(emailId, subject, body, rpt, fileName);
            //}
        }
    }
```